# Speaker on bicycle - would it propel the rider forward?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, acceleration, velocity

[image]

You strap a super powerful speaker on your back, blast it on max volume. **Would it propel you forward?**

Comment: I think it depends on what the source of energy for the speaker is.

Comment: @aventurin let's say the speaker has huge battery inside

Answer (score 2):

No. The speaker cone moves back and forth as it produces sound, alternately pulling and pushing on the box into which it is bolted. The net force, averaged over time, is zero, and the box will not exert a constant pushing force on you.

Comment: Yes, but there's also an unisotropic transmission of sound energy resulting in an unisotropic distribution of sound pressure. I would find it surprising if its interaction with the environment would not result in a net force on the bicyclist.